# Maximum weight for robot arm - MG996R

Tags: arduino, physics, robotics, arduino-uno, robot

I want to build a robot arm (see [here](https://youtu.be/F0ZvF-FbCr0)) to move a dumbbell of 2 kg (roughly 2.2 lbs).

However, since I have no background in engineering, I have no idea how to calculate / find out if the servos used (MG996R) have enough power to lift the object. How do I solve it? What is the conclusion?

If you come to the conclusion it doesn't have enough power, can you recommend an Arduino-enabled servo that does have sufficient power?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please include a link to the datasheet of the servo and post an image of what you want. Most people like to go watch some video and google for your servo just to answer your question.

Comment: You need to specify a rough mechanical design before anyone can begin to answer. The torque necessary will depend on the arm length. The first website I found for the MG996r used torque units that make no sense, so I don't trust it. My gut feel is that you want something 5-10 times more powerful.

Comment: 2 kg != 2.2 lbs

Answer (score 1):

The servo you selected is a high-torque one. It's defined as 10 kg·cm. This means with an arm length of 1 cm it can lift 10kg. So simple physics tells us that at 2 cm it can lift half of that  and at 5 cm 1/5th, etc.

So your robot arm would have to be really small and never extend more than 5 cm from the axis of rotation to be able to handle 2 kg.

It's up to you to define if that's enough for what you need.